# Building a project around Bing translate and Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure

I am trying to build a web app that allows a user to press a button and translate a piece of text using the Bing translator api. I try to run a translator.js file through a script tag but I of course cannot run this node.js code through the client html page. What would be the proper way to design this app. Is my only choice to use something such as requirejs? I also have an app.js file built using express from which I run the app. Sorry for posting a lot of code, I want to give people an idea of the structure of my app. My experience is limited so I am feeling somewhat lost as to how to approach the design of this portion of the app. I don't expect anyone to write the code for me, but to just point in a direction of techniques that I could research so that I could build this properly.

Here is my Node.js translation request called translator.js

```
const request = require('request');
const uuidv4 = require('uuid/v4');


var key_var = 'TRANSLATOR_TEXT_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY';
if (!process.env[key_var]) {
    throw new Error('Please set/export the following environment variable: ' + key_var);
}
var subscriptionKey = process.env[key_var];
var endpoint_var = 'TRANSLATOR_TEXT_ENDPOINT';
if (!process.env[endpoint_var]) {
    throw new Error('Please set/export the following environment variable: ' + endpoint_var);
}
var endpoint = process.env[endpoint_var];



let options = {
    method: 'POST',
    baseUrl: endpoint,
    url: 'translate',
    qs: {
      'api-version': '3.0',
      'to': ['en']
    },
    headers: {
      'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscriptionKey,
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      'X-ClientTraceId': uuidv4().toString()
    },
    body: [{
          'text': 'hallo welt'
    }],
    json: true,
};



function displayBingTranslate() {
  request(options, function(err, res, body){
    document.querySelector("#bingTranslateOutput") = JSON.stringify(body, null, 4);
  });
};


var accessBingTranslate = document.getElementById("accessBingTranslateButton");

accessBingTranslate.addEventListener("click", function() {
  displayBingTranslate();
});
```

And here is my html

```
    <!-- Section to view online translation -->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12 p-0">
            <button 
              class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm mb-1"
                  id = "accessBingTranslateButton">Translate Flashcard</button>
                <div class="row m-0 p-0">
                  <div id="bingTranslateOutput" class="col-lg-12 m-0">
                  </div>


    <script>

    // Overall list of flashcards.
    var flashcardList = {

      flashcards: [],

      // Adds a flashcard object to Flashcard array.
      addFlashcard: function(fcTextQuestion, fcTextTranslated) {
        this.flashcards.push({
          fcTextQuestion: fcTextQuestion,
          fcTextTranslated: fcTextTranslated
        });
      }, 

    };

    // Add flashcards on load.
    var flashcardsDB = <%- JSON.stringify(flashcardsDB) %>;
    console.log("the DB:", flashcardsDB);
    flashcardsDB.forEach(function(fcardDbToAdd){
      flashcardList.addFlashcard(fcardDbToAdd.question, fcardDbToAdd.translation);
    });
    document.querySelector("#displayFlashcardTotal").textContent = flashcardList.flashcards.length;

    console.log("the rest:",flashcardList.flashcards);

    var currentFlashcard = 0;


    </script>



<script src="/scripts/translator.js"></script>       


      </body>


</html>
```

and here is my app.js

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var methodOverride = require("method-override");

// Fix mongoose deprecations
mongoose.set('useNewUrlParser', true);
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);
mongoose.set('useUnifiedTopology', true);

// Connect to database.
var url = "///////";
mongoose.connect(url, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
}).then(() => {
    console.log("connected to mongoDB");
}).catch(err => {
    console.log("Error:", err.message);
});
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
// Set 'views' directory for any views 
// being rendered res.render()
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

// Override HTTP verbs if necessary.
app.use(methodOverride("_method"));

var flashcardSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    question: String,
    translation: String
});

//creates model with above schema and has methods such as .find etc.
var Flashcard = mongoose.model("Flashcard", flashcardSchema); 

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  Flashcard.find({}, function(err, allFlashcards){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.render("home", {flashcardsDB: allFlashcards});
    }
  }); 
});

// Post to an input action
app.post("/flashcards", function(req, res) {
    var question = req.body.question;
    var translation = req.body.translation;
    var newFlashcard = {question: question, translation: translation};
    console.log(newFlashcard);
    Flashcard.create(newFlashcard, function(err, newlyCreated){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.redirect("/flashcards");
        }
    });
});

// Show info.
app.get("/info",function (req, res) {
    res.render("info");
});

// Show all flashcards
app.get("/flashcards", function(req, res){
    Flashcard.find({}, function(err, allFlashcards){
      if(err){
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        res.render("flashcards", {flashcards: allFlashcards});
      }
    }); 
});

// Show form to create new campground
app.get("/new", function(req, res){
  res.render("new");  
});

// Edit flashcard
app.get("/flashcards/:id/edit", function(req, res){
    Flashcard.findById(req.params.id, function(err, selectedFlashcard){
      if(err){
            req.flash("error", "Flashcard not found!");
          } else {
            res.render("edit", {flashcard: selectedFlashcard});
          }
    });  
});

// Update flashcard
app.put("/flashcards/:id", function(req, res){
  Flashcard.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body.flashcard, function(err, updatedFlashcard){
    if(err){
      res.redirect("/flashcards");
    } else {
      res.redirect("/flashcards");
    }
  });  
});

// Destroy Flashcard
app.delete("/flashcards/:id", function(req, res){
    Flashcard.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, function(err){
      if(err){
            res.redirect("back");
          } else {
        //req.flash("success", "flashcard deleted.");
            res.redirect("/flashcards");
          }
    });
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log("Flashcard app is listening"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best aproach would be to pass the translator.js to the node.js server. Create a route on express for translations, and through that route you will call the translator.js and return the result. Then, on your html page, instead of running the translator.js directly, send a request to your server passing the necessary data.

On your app.js, you can do a route like this:

```
const translator = require('path_to_translator');
app.get('/translation', translator);
```

And then on your translator.js, you can export a function that will receive the parameters you need and return the result:

```
const bingTranslate = (req, res) => {
// YOUR CODE HERE
}

module.exports = bingTranslate
```

And then on your html you will make the button send a request to your server instead of calling translator.js, so you can change the value of the #bingTranslateOutput button based on the response you will receive from the server.

Comment: Should I use a get or a post request?

Comment: The structure I wrote is for a GET request. You can use a POST if you want, but i'd say a GET makes more sense in this case.